# Error CS0012 The type 'XmlReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I am facing below errors in one of my project when i choose the project  template Service Fabric -> Asp.Net Core -> Web API but same works fine if choose direct .Net core template. Only difference i see is .Net framework in Service Fabric -> Asp.Net Core -> Web API framework version is 4.5.2 to while in direct template its 4.6.1

In case of direct template I only need to add System.Xml.Serilizer dependency while in case of service fabric It start complaining about System.XML

```
private void SerialiseModelTypeToStream(TextWriter writer, 
      object model, Type objectType)
    {
        var serializer = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objectType);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, model);
    }
```

{

"version": "1.0.0-*"

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
"System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.10"
```

},

"frameworks": {
    "net452": {

```
}
```

}
}

Error   CS0012  The type 'XmlReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    AddressLookUp.SOAP..NET Framework 4.5.2

Error   CS0012  The type 'XmlWriter' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    AddressLookUp.SOAP..NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Have you tried to manually add reference to System.Xml assembly? I just tried the template chosen from Service Fabric, it works fine. I wonder whether you missed referencing the assembly.

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding reference manually but then other start breaking i mean system.xml.serialization one

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add this DLL as Reference:

```
 cs0012.dll
 if not then this dlls cs0012b.dll;cs0012a.dll
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hi Reds, I didn't get you, how to add reference to these dlls I am not getting in add reference dialog box.

Comment: Issue got resolved, problem was with project.json file